# "module fs cannot be found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

i have used `var module = require('/path/to/node_modules/module-name')` and all of my other models get recognized but `fs` does not get recognized even though I've pointed to where it is and made sure that its installed?? i do not understand, please help

my console gives out this:
http://prntscr.com/g2akvs

but all my other modules are fine

as you can see by my referencing:
http://prntscr.com/g2akzm

Comment: `fs` is a native nodejs module, it sould be imported as is: `let fs = require('fs');`

Comment: tried it but it doesnt work :/

Comment: The same error?

Comment: yes it does, i had to remove the file path and change it to just ('fs')

Comment: i mean to say it about working*

Comment: thank you, i will note that for next time :)

Comment: Please post your code and the error message in your question, instead of linking pictures.

Comment: When you use `require('fs')`, node has a hierarchy that it looks for the module. I don't recall exactly what it is, but it basically first checks if it is a native module, then it checks the folder `node_modules`, then it checks the root of the project, etc.

Comment: I got this error because I did `node -c 'console.log("hi")'` instead of `node -e`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In node.js, `fs` is a native, built-in module.  You include it without any path as in:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Here's the list of built-in libs from the [node.js source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/module.js#L79):

```
const builtinLibs = [
  'assert', 'async_hooks', 'buffer', 'child_process', 'cluster', 'crypto',
  'dgram', 'dns', 'domain', 'events', 'fs', 'http', 'https', 'net', 'os',
  'path', 'punycode', 'querystring', 'readline', 'repl', 'stream',
  'string_decoder', 'tls', 'tty', 'url', 'util', 'v8', 'vm', 'zlib'
];
```

Comment: And for typescript projects you can install node types `npm install --save-dev @types/node` and import it `import fs from "fs";`