# Check for string in file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In a nutshell, what I want is for a javascript function to check a file for an HTML input.
I have tried using doing as this post told me to: [Javascript check if (txt) file contains string/variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449133/javascript-check-if-txt-file-contains-string-variable/30242363) 
But kept getting an error saying `ReferenceError: fs is not defined` 
So now I am here asking for help.

Comment: fs for node not for browser.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405517/module-fs-cannot-be-found

Comment: Hi Kaiden, your question could benefit from some example source code. For future reference please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might just need to import fs. At the top of your script add: `const fs = require('fs');`

Comment: So understanding that I cannot use fs, but what can I do then?

Comment: If you're trying to do this in a browser, you could [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the file and use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be sure because you didn't provide any example code, but `fs` usually refers to "file system" in [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)
So the answer from the other topic isn't complete but the import is implied by it's usage:

```js
var fs = require("fs")

fs.readFile(FILE_LOCATION, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if(data.indexOf('search string') >= 0){
   console.log(data)
  }
});
```

But like some other commentors have said, this is for nodejs and not in the browser.

Comment: [data.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) answers the question more directly than `indexOf` and might be more performant.

Comment: @rayhatfield searching for a string in a file (txt file as example) not a string in a string.

Comment: @KaidenSmith I'm referring to his use of `indexOf` in the callback, where `data` *is a string or buffer*, both of which support `includes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this in a browser, you could [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the url and use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check for the string you're looking for:

```js
async function responseContains(url, string) {
  try {
    const content = await fetch(url).then(response => response.text());
    return content.includes(string);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
}

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
/*
  the url above returns:
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  }
*/

responseContains(url, 'userId')
  .then(found => console.log(`Found 'userId'? ${found}`));
// Found? true

responseContains(url, 'wookies with bananas')
  .then(found => console.log(`Found 'wookies with bananas'? ${found}`));
// Found? false
```